# how to bind data to templated combobox using WPF MVVM prism technology?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

```
 Am very very beginner in WPF and MVVM architcture using PRISM.
```

How to bind data to temaplted combobox ?
        I've a observablecollection of strings which is a master data  and a list of entities of Type in viewmodel.
        observablecollection  = {data1 , data2 ,data3 , data4 , data5,..}
        entity
        {
         string name; int Pricevalue;
        }
        List = {{data1,13}, {data5,23}  }
        when the observale collection matches one of the data inentities then checkbox of combobox should be checked and its value should be displayed in textbox
        In xaml markup there is a templated combobox which has textbox and checkbox bound to above observablecollection of string.
        and there is another textbox which holds one of the properties of entity.
        the templated combo box must be checked for all the trings which are in common to list of entities.
        and the combo box should display first checked box item and its corresponding entiti property in the other textbox.

```
    Pls help in writing up the markup  and the conditions to bind the data to templated combo box and textbox.
```

am getting errors or not properly able to code

Comment: could you add your source code, it will help us to understand your problem?